# How do I create a multiline wxNotebook for gtk?

Tags: gtk, wxwidgets, wxnotebook

wxWidgets provides for notebooks with multiple lines of tabs only on Windows platforms.  Is there a simple way to provide similar functionality on GTK based platforms, or am I stuck with the only option being to create a customized notebook class that supports it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, you are stuck with the only option being to create a customized notebook class that supports it. GTK solves the "too many tabs" problem by providing left and right arrows with which you can page through the tabs.

Multiline tabs are a horrible idea anyway in my opinion. Take a look at [these monstrosities](http://homepage.mac.com/bradster/iarchitect/tabs.htm).